# Is Senketsu eye patterns from Kill la Kill based off something?

Tags: kill-la-kill, blassreiter

I was watching *Blassreiter* and I noticed that the back of Hermann's jacket has the same eyes as Senketsu from *Kill la Kill*.

[image: Senketsu from Kill la Kill] [image: The back of Hermann's jacket with eye patterns]

Are those eye patterns mean something or if they are just a playful nod from one anime to another?

Comment: Blassreiter is from 2008 and Kill la Kill is from 2013 so it could be a nod to it.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be one coincidence, they do share some similarities and some large differences. This was asked on the Kill La Kill reddit 3 years ago and remains unanswered. I guess you would have to get the character artists and ask them...

My assumption would be that it is just a coincidence, the lines from the tops of the eyes, both showing, multiple layers and the pupil being the main differences.

A large part of Kill La Kill's plot is the Life Fibers, which make up the clothes. Eyes being on the clothes is a design choice, which makes sense as they are living.

Comment: It might be a nod and a bit of foreshadowing, seeing as how the demoniacs infect humans, and senkentsu/kill la kill clothing does the entire attempt-to-take-over-the-world through infecting everyone via monopolizing the clothing industry...